# Flutter: Fill ListView.builder from existing list with 2 widgets per row

Tags: android, flutter, listview, widget, row

I tried so far and fail so hard by making than my `ListView.builder` show 2 widgets per row by taking the data from a `List<MyCustomWidget> customs`.

my **List** is like:

```
Class CustomWidgetData extends changeNotifier {
  List<CustomWidget> customs = [
    CustomWidget(
      icon: Icons.add,
      iconColor: Colors.green,
    ),
  ];
}
```

my **ListView.builder** is like:

```
class CustomWidgetListBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<CustomWidgetData>(
      builder: (context, customWidgetData, child) {
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              final customWidget = customWidgetData.customs[index];
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: CustomWidget(
                    icon:customWidget.icon,
                    iconColor: customWidget.iconColor,
                  ),//CustomWidget
                ),//Expanded
                ],
              );//Row
            },
            itemCount: customWidgetData.customs.lenght,
          ), //ListView.builder
        ); //Expanded
      },
    );//Consumer
  }
}
```

[How I want it to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfqiK.png)

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R45N.png)

In the first image i'm only added other Expanded->CustomWidget inside the Row of my **ListView.builder** but it repeat all the list and I want smth like:

```
1|2
3|4
5|6
...
```

Comment: You can use gridView: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listview is not best suited for this use case. There is another widget called GridView which generates grids like what you wanted.

```
GridView.builder(
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
            maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
            childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 20,
            mainAxisSpacing: 20),
        itemCount: customWidgetData.customs.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index) {
          return Container();
          
        }),
```